# How to keep scroll bar position...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my web page i have a jquery calendar to selected multiple dates.When i select each date the calendar will refresh to highlight the selected date.Now the problem is that each time i am select a date the page is also going to top of the page.How can i keep the page in position and select dates again and again..?

Here is my js

```js
$( "#datepickerr" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' , 
    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    todayHighlight: true,
    // showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShowDay: function ( date ) {
        if(date.getTime() >= date1 && date.getTime() <= date2){
            return[true,'date-range',''];
        }
        else{
            return [true, ( (date.getTime() >= Math.min(prv, cur) && date.getTime() <= Math.max(prv, cur)) ? 'date-range' : '')];
        }
    },
    onSelect: function ( dateText, inst ) {
        var d1, d2;
        prv = cur;
        cur = (new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay)).getTime();
        if ( prv == -1 || prv == cur ) {
            prv = cur;
            date1=date2=prv ;
            $('#datepickerr').val( dateText ); 
            $('#datepickerr').datepicker("refresh");   
        } else {
            d1 = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy-mm-dd', new Date(Math.min(prv,cur)), {} );
            d2 = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy-mm-dd', new Date(Math.max(prv,cur)), {} );
            date1=d1;
            date=d2;
            $('#datepickerr').val( d1+'  '+d2 );   
            $('#datepickerr').datepicker("refresh");                   
        }
        hideDatepicker(null);
    }
});
```

Comment: use work around to highlight,do not refresh,for example gave each day in calendar a special class refer to date and use $.css to highlight, still u can record scrollTop and set it after refresh, and that feels bad

Comment: can u give me the code

Answer (score -1):

general idea

```js
var selected = [];

$("#datepickerr").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var index = selected.indexOf(dateText);
    if (index !== false) {
      $('.d-' + dateText).removeClass('selected');
      selected.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      $('.d-' + dateText).addClass('selected');
      selected.push(dateText)

    }

  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  /* your highlight style */
}
```

```html
<!-- <tag class="d-dateText"><tag class="d-dateText"><tag class="d-dateText"><tag class="d-dateText"> -->
```

Comment: there are some another date range to be highlighted before selecting a date.and here i am not selecting a single date but a range of days so can you tell me how to prevent the reload action

Comment: @iqbalpalemad do not use $('#datepickerr').datepicker("refresh"); so highlight should be done through another way(not datepicker provided) and i can provide my idea only. selecting range need more fix on this, also u can try some other datepicker which wont reload

Comment: Now i tried it after removing the refresh line but the problem still existing.Now i found that the problem is in onselect function when i select a date it adds a # with the url

Comment: @iqbalpalemad maybe your runtime html looks like <a href="#"> inspect the elements to test, the anchor link made page top, <a> or <a href="###"> don't have this problem, i need your fiddle to get a full understand

Comment: <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a>     i found this when i inspect my page

Comment: @iqbalpalemad  try $('a[href=#]').attr('href','###') after datepicker inited for a quick fix